# Use currentLocation along with a business search in bing map API

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I was currently at [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259692.aspx) which shows how to implement business search using the bing map api. But what I am trying to implement is, first the map should get your current location and search for type of business nearby, let's say Restaurant or Check Cashing place.
[My current page](http://www.sikni8.com/map.htm) has the current location working but now how I implement the FindNearBy function with my page?

P.s. I want the search to already take place for the user without having to enter a search text, so the map should load up with current location and right next to it should list all or maybe the closest 5 restaurant nearby.

Comment: got it
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912031/get-business-type-industry-from-bing-phonebook-api/7002207#7002207][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912031/get-business-type-industry-from-bing-phonebook-api/7002207#7002207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with Bing Maps...you need the Bing Phonebook API to do this.

I can get you part of the way there. The below example combines the use of both the Bing Maps API and the Bing Phonebook API) I just submitted a similar question about how to find the type of business, however...I'm not sure there's a wayto do this :/ (Below example searches for all Starbucks in the area ...of course, some HTML integration is required.

```
var _map;
var _appId;

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
        $(".geofallback").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".geofallback").show();
    }
    $.post("Home/GetBingMapsKey", { "func": "GetBingMapsKey" }, function (data) {
        // Create a Bing map
        _map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            { credentials: data }); //, mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.ordnanceSurvey
    });

    // Get the current position from the browser
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        $("#results").html("This browser doesn't support geolocation, please enter an address");
    }
else {
        $.post("Home/GetBingKey", { "func": "GetBingKey" }, function (data) {
            _appId = data;
        });
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionReady, onError);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(Search, onError);
    }
});

function onPositionReady(position) {

    // Apply the position to the map
    var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude);

    _map.setView({ zoom: 18, center: location });

    // Add a pushpin to the map representing the current location
    var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location);
    _map.entities.push(pin);

}

function onError(err) {
    switch (err.code) {
        case 0:
            alert("Unknown error :(");
            break;
        case 1:
            alert("Location services are unavailable per your request.");
            break;
        case 2:
            alert("Location data is unavailable.");
            break;
        case 3:
            alert("The location request has timed out. Please contact support if you continue to experience issues.");
            break;
    }
}

function Search(position) {
          // note a bunch of this code uses the example code from
          // Microsoft for the Phonebook API
    var requestStr = "http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?"

        // Common request fields (required)
        + "AppId=" + _appId
        + "&Query=starbucks"
        + "&Sources=Phonebook"

        // Common request fields (optional)
        + "&Version=2.2"
        + "&Market=en-us"
        + "&UILanguage=en"
        + "&Latitude=" + position.coords.latitude
        + "&Longitude=" + position.coords.longitude
        + "&Radius=100.0"
        + "&Options=EnableHighlighting"

        // Phonebook-specific request fields (optional)

        // Phonebook.Count max val is 25
        + "&Phonebook.Count=25"
        + "&Phonebook.Offset=0"
        // YP = Commercial Entity, WP = Residential
        + "&Phonebook.FileType=YP"
        + "&Phonebook.SortBy=Distance"

        // JSON-specific request fields (optional)
        + "&JsonType=callback"
        + "&JsonCallback=?";

    $.getJSON(requestStr, function (data) {
        SearchCompleted(data);
    });
}

function FormatBingQuery(appId, latitude ) {
}

function SearchCompleted(response) {
    var errors = response.SearchResponse.Errors;
    if (errors != null) {
        // There are errors in the response. Display error details.
        DisplayErrors(errors);
    }
    else {
        // There were no errors in the response. Display the
        // Phonebook results.
        DisplayResults(response);
    }
}

function DisplayResults(response) {

    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var resultsHeader = document.createElement("h4");
    var resultsList = document.createElement("ul");
    output.appendChild(resultsHeader);
    output.appendChild(resultsList);

    var results = response.SearchResponse.Phonebook.Results;

    // Display the results header.
    resultsHeader.innerHTML = "Bing API Version "
            + response.SearchResponse.Version
            + "<br />Phonebook results for "
            + response.SearchResponse.Query.SearchTerms
            + "<br />Displaying "
            + (response.SearchResponse.Phonebook.Offset + 1)
            + " to "
            + (response.SearchResponse.Phonebook.Offset + results.length)
            + " of "
            + response.SearchResponse.Phonebook.Total
            + " results<br />";

    // Display the Phonebook results.
    var resultsListItem = null;
    var resultStr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        resultsListItem = document.createElement("li");
        resultsList.appendChild(resultsListItem);
                    //loc is specific to my C# object
        var loc = new Array();
        loc[0] = results[i].Longitude;
        loc[1] = results[i].Latitude;

        var address = {
            AddressLine1: results[i].Address,
            City: results[i].City,
            State: results[i].StateOrProvince,
            PostalCode: results[i].PostalCode,
            Latitude: results[i].Latitude,
            Longitude: results[i].Longitude,
            Country: results[i].CountryOrRegion,
            ID: results[i].UniqueId
        };
                    //this part is specific to my project to return the 
                    //address results so I can store them (since my
                    //implementation is a demonstration of how to 
                    //use the MongoDB geoNear() functionality
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AddAddressToCollection",
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(address),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        resultStr = results[i].Business
                + "<br />"
                + results[i].Address
                + "<br />"
                + results[i].City
                + ", "
                + results[i].StateOrProvince
                + "<br />"
                + results[i].PhoneNumber
                + "<br />Average Rating: "
                + results[i].UserRating
                + "<br /><br />";

        // Replace highlighting characters with strong tags.
        resultsListItem.innerHTML = ReplaceHighlightingCharacters(
                resultStr,
                "<strong>",
                "</strong>");
    }
}

function ReplaceHighlightingCharacters(text, beginStr, endStr) {
    // Replace all occurrences of U+E000 (begin highlighting) with
    // beginStr. Replace all occurrences of U+E001 (end highlighting)
    // with endStr.
    var regexBegin = new RegExp("\uE000", "g");
    var regexEnd = new RegExp("\uE001", "g");

    return text.replace(regexBegin, beginStr).replace(regexEnd, endStr);
}

function DisplayErrors(errors) {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var errorsHeader = document.createElement("h4");
    var errorsList = document.createElement("ul");
    output.appendChild(errorsHeader);
    output.appendChild(errorsList);

    // Iterate over the list of errors and display error details.
    errorsHeader.innerHTML = "Errors:";
    var errorsListItem = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; ++i) {
        errorsListItem = document.createElement("li");
        errorsList.appendChild(errorsListItem);
        errorsListItem.innerHTML = "";
        for (var errorDetail in errors[i]) {
            errorsListItem.innerHTML += errorDetail
                    + ": "
                    + errors[i][errorDetail]
                    + "<br />";
        }

        errorsListItem.innerHTML += "<br />";
    }
} 

    // Bonus: In case you want to provide directions
    // for how to get to a selected entity

    //            _map.getCredentials(function (credentials) {
    //                $.getJSON('http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/driving?' + 'wp.0=' + lat1 + ',' + lon1 + '&wp.1=' + lat2 + ',' + lon2 + '&distanceUnit=mi&optmz=distance&key=' + credentials + '&jsonp=?&s=1',
    //                function (result) {
    //                    if (result.resourceSets[0].estimatedTotal > 0) {
    //                        var distance = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].travelDistance;
    //                    }
    //                    else {
    //                        $("#results").html("Oops! It appears one or more of the addresses you entered are incorrect. :( ");
    //                    }
    //                });
    //            });

//Tie into a function that shows an input field
//for use as a fallback in case cannot use HTML5 geoLocation
//$(document).ready(function () {
//    $("#btnFindLocation").click(function () {
//        //check user has entered something first
//        if ($("#txtAddress").val().length > 0) {
//            //send location query to bing maps REST api
//            _map.getCredentials(function (credentials) {
//                $.getJSON('http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=' + $("#txtAddress").val() + '&key=' + credentials + '&jsonp=?&s=1', 
//                    function (result) {
//                        if (result.resourceSets[0].estimatedTotal > 0) {
//                            var loc = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
//                            $("#lat").val(loc[0]);
//                            $("#lon").val(loc[1]);
//                            var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(loc[0],
//                                loc[1]);
//                            _map.setView({ zoom: 18, center: location });
//                            // Add a pushpin to the map representing the current location
//                            var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location);
//                            _map.entities.push(pin);
//                        }
//                        else {
//                            $("#results").html("sorry that address cannot be found");
//                        }
//                });
//            });
//        }
//        else {
//            $("#results").html("please enter an address");
//        }
//    });
//});
```

Comment: Actually this is what you need to get the address...but I think there's a way to find entity types with Bing Maps although it may only be public or emergency types like government buildings or hospitals...I will look into it and update my response

Comment: Ok let me know what you find, i really appreciate it Martin! :)! Its actually for a project i am working on!