# Bing Phonebook API in auto complete?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, bing-api

Anyone know whether it is possible to get the Bing Phonebook API in Autocomplete textbox?

I am working on an application, in which I want to provide an option to add restaurants to there list, I am planning to get the restaurants from bing and wondering is it possible to provide them in Auto Complete option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you Need an App-ID.
You can get one at http://www.bing.com/developers/ (5000 Transactions are free).

Then follow: [Get business type/industry from Bing Phonebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912031/get-business-type-industry-from-bing-phonebook-api)